# How can I trace my code step by step like F7 just on project files

Tags: android

For example when I trace step by step not jump to library files.
Just line by line in current class file or projects files.
Is it possible?
Stay in `MyApp.java` and not go to `Dex.java`

Example image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

Press F8 instead of F7 it will go directly to the next line in that class.

Comment: Tanx, I tried it and other function keys previously but I absent minded on it ;)

Comment: if suppose there are 1000 lines in your code in single class, If you want to skip line by line for eg: first debug point is on line 300 and you don't want to go step by step, then you can add another breakpoint, say 700 and then press green play button on debugger then it will directly jump to that debug point.

Comment: Tnx Demo Mail. I got it.